# how did they use this integral identity?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, special-functions

\begin{align} 
\int_0^\infty P(\omega) \, d\omega 
&= \int_0^\infty \frac A4 \int_0^\infty d\omega \, 
\frac{h\omega^3}{\pi^2 c^2} 
\cdot \frac{1}{\exp\bigl(\frac{h\omega}{k_B T}\bigr) - 1} \\[2pt] 
&= \frac{Ah}{4\pi^2 c^2} \int_0^\infty d\omega 
\frac{\omega^3}{\exp\bigl(\frac{h\omega}{k_B T}\bigr) - 1}
\end{align}
and then he uses the an integral identity, I don't know its name, but I'd like to know
$$ 
\int_0^\infty \frac{\omega^3}{e^\omega -1} \, d\omega 
= \frac{\pi^4}{15}
$$
and then he gets
$$ 
P = \frac{Ah}{4\pi^2 c^2} \cdot \frac{\pi^4(k_B T)^4}{15h^4} 
= \frac{A\pi^2k_B^4 T^4}{60c^2 h^3}
$$

How did he transform
$$
\int_0^\infty d\omega \, 
\frac{\omega^3}{\exp\bigl(\frac{h\omega}{k_B T}\bigr) - 1}
$$
with the integral identity mentioned before to
$$
\frac{\pi^4(k_B T)^4}{15h^4}.
$$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A simple change of variable followed by the integral of the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Definition) may help...

Comment: The substitution $\mu=\frac{h\omega}{k_B T}$ in the integral then use your identity.

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni How are you, Raymond ?

Comment: Hi @JeanMarie! I am fine thank you. Hope you are well too. Cheers,

Comment: Just let $u$ equal the inside of the exponential then use the identity, assuming that $\frac{h}{k_B T}$ is positive.

Comment: @paul I dont quite understand, how to use the substitution, could you show it to me explicitily?

Comment: $\int_0^\infty dx \frac{x^3}{\exp(\frac{x}{a}) - 1}=\int_0^\infty adu \frac{a^3u^3}{\exp(u) - 1}=\int_0^\infty a^4du \frac{u^3}{\exp(u) - 1}$ where $u=\frac{x}{a}$